# Specify 'label' and 'value' attribute for dijit.form.Select

Tags: javascript, dojo

I was using `dijit.form.ComboBox`, but the requirement has changed, and now `dijit.form.Select` is more appropriate.

However, after changing the widget type I get an error:

> TypeError: _b6d.getLabel is not a function

From the documentation http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/Select.html I see that `dijit.form.Select` expect fields `id` and `label` in the Store, while my Store has `id` and `name`.

The documentation gives no example how to override that defaults. So, how can I specify the `id` and `label` attributes for `dijit.form.Select`?

My data looks like that:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Item 1"},{"id":2,"name":"Item 2"},{"id":3,"name":"Item 3"}]
```

In case it's not possible, what dijit widget can I use for selection restricted only to items from Store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `labelAttr` property on the `dijit/form/Select` which you can use to change the name of the label attribute.

For example:

```
new Select({
    store: myStore,
    labelAttr: "name" // Now the name attribute will be used
}, "mySelect");
```

If you also like to change the attribute used for the ID (it's not necessary in this case, but you asked how to specify that one as well), then you should look at the `idProperty` of the `dojo/store/Memory`, for example:

```
var myStore = new Memory({
    idProperty: "id",
    data: [{
        "id":1,
        "name":"Item 1"
    }, {
        "id":2,
        "name":"Item 2"
    }, {
        "id":3,
        "name":"Item 3"
    }]
});
```

A full example can be found on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NvKgH/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [FilteringSelect](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/FilteringSelect.html) to restrict the selection to only the items that are in the store. And it shouldn't be much trouble to implement it, because both `ComboBox` and `FilteringSelect` use `dijit/form/ComboBoxMixin` to provide the combobox functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misread the documentation.
It mentions over [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/Select.html#a-select-fed-by-a-store) that the data from the store **must** have **id** and **label** attributes, not value and label attributes.
The **id** of the **store** will be the **value** you get using the get("value") call.
For getting the **value** you need to use **get("value")** function on the widget i.e

```
widget.get("value")
```

and for **label** I am assuming that it is

```
widget.get("label")


[{"id":1,"name":"Item 1","label":"Item 1"},{"id":2,"name":"Item 2","label":"Item 2"},{"id":3,"name":"Item 3","label":"Item 3"}]
```

Comment: Well, it didn't change as much. My data doesn't have `label` attribute. I need to say that the Select should use `name` instead. Otherwise it won't work.